# Can a dynamic type function param be extended?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is this a possibility (and if so how)?

```
type extendedValues = { name: string };

type Props<T> {
  values: T & extendedValues ?
}

const ReactFuncComponent = <T extends Props<T>>({ values }: Props<T>) => {
...
}
```

So essentially I want to say you can pass in an object that contains any fields with any values but it must also include a name of type string:

```
<ReactFuncComponent values={{ age: 0, name: '' }} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can achieve what you want in following way:

```js
interface Credentials {
  name: string;
}

type ExtendedValues<T> = Credentials & T;

type Props<T> = {
   value: ExtendedValues<T>
}

const TestComponent = <T, >(props: Props<T>) => {
  return <p>Some text here</p>
};

// Example of usage

<TestComponent value={{name: "Name"}} /> // Will be OK
<TestComponent value={{name: "Name", age: 25}} /> // Will be OK
<TestComponent value={{age: 25}} /> // Error: property 'name' is missing
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Seems I missed the , in the function const TestComponent = <T, >(props: Props<T>) when testing things out. Not sure why this makes it work so will do some googling. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. Yeap, that's a bit confusing. As far as I know, you will get this issue with generics in .tsx files. In .ts files you won't see that kind of error with arrow functions and generics. As far as I know, in this case, TS compiler can't understand that it's generic, so you are getting an error.